# Adding console output to NUnit test results

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-console, nunit-2.5

I have been trying to figure out a way to add some string output to NUnit test results. I did some research and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025298/putting-console-output-from-nunit-tests-into-the-xml-results#_=_), but this is not what I want. I want to write the output to the result `xml` generated by NUnit, but I cannot find a way to do it. Please suggest!

I aware that NUnit 3 will have a mechanism called *[TextContex](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=3.0)* to accomplish something similar, but I am using *2.6.3*.

Comment: im not sure whether the `message` parameter in `Assert`-statements would get into the xml files. if so, maybe you could achieve what you want that way?

Comment: Do you want to open an XML file and then modify results, or are you getting the xml file through a string?  You should be able to modify any xml through c#.  It doesn't matter that the source came from nunit.

Comment: @nozzleman I am trying to write as if I am using `Console.Writeline()`

Comment: @jdweng I want to add them runtime which is related the current test case

Comment: Can't use write line.  An XML file can only have one root node like <Root>.......</Root>.  You can't just write new nodes at end of file because you will have multiple nodes at the Root level.

Comment: As search engines also lead to here (false positive) looking for ways of ***providing output to the screen for debugging unit tests*** ([print debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Techniques)) implemented with NUnit: *[How do I get nunit3-console to output my debug to screen (on a Windows box)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405753/)*. It is essentially `TestContext.WriteLine`. It works on Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of `PropertyAttribute`s to attach properties per test to the XML output. The example below assumes you really want to use `Console.WriteLine` to produce string output, but you could always make your own `TestConsole.WriteLine` or something if you don't want to mess with the console output.

E.g. this attribute says to attach an "Output" property to each test it's declared on:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class TestWriterAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public TestWriterAttribute() : base()
    {
        // Create a container for test output
        Properties["Output"] = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

And this attribute says to redirect `Console.Out` to your "Output" property (again, you can use your own `TestConsole` kind of class instead of using this attribute if you don't want to mess with `Console.Out`).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ConsoleOutToTestWriterAttribute : TestActionAttribute
{
    public override void BeforeTest(TestDetails testDetails)
    {
        // If the test has a [TestWriter], redirect Console.Out to its "Output" property
        var output = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Output"] as StringBuilder;
        if (output != null) 
            Console.SetOut(new System.IO.StringWriter(output));
        _consoleOutRedirected = output != null;
    }

    public override void AfterTest(TestDetails testDetails)
    {
        // Reset Console.Out, if appropriate
        if(_consoleOutRedirected)
            Console.SetOut(new System.IO.StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()) { AutoFlush = true });
    }

    public override ActionTargets Targets
    {
        // needs to apply to each test, since [TestWriter]s are applied per test
        get { return ActionTargets.Test; }
    }

    private bool _consoleOutRedirected;
}
```

And your tests can just use `Console.WriteLine` which will be captured per test:

```
[ConsoleOutToTestWriter] // redirect Console.Out into "Output" property per test
public class ClassTest
{
    [Test]
    [TestWriter] // adds "Output" property
    public void MyTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test 123");
        Console.WriteLine("321 test");
    }

    [Test]
    [TestWriter]
    public void MyTest2()
    {
        // this console output will be written to this test's own "Output"
        Console.WriteLine("test2 123");
        Console.WriteLine("321 test2");
    }
}
```

Which produces the following under `<results>` in the NUnit XML output:

```
<test-case name="SO_31092459.ClassTest.MyTest" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.023" asserts="0">
    <properties>
        <property name="Output" value="test 123&#xD;&#xA;321 test&#xD;&#xA;" />
    </properties>
</test-case>
<test-case name="SO_31092459.ClassTest.MyTest2" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.000" asserts="0">
    <properties>
        <property name="Output" value="test2 123&#xD;&#xA;321 test2&#xD;&#xA;" />
    </properties>
</test-case>
```

Comment: Nice exposure to the TestActionAttribute!